# .csv too many rows to upload?

Tags: php, csv

I don't really know much PHP. But anyways I am not able to upload a .csv file using the following php. The file is less the 5MB. What's going on? There are a total of 79,500 rows of records with just four columns and simple value like such:

```
27589   16990   161.7000095 0.838494
27589   17067   161.7000095 0.838494
27820   17144   315.7000095 0.859458
27820   17221   315.7000095 0.859458
27820   17606   315.7000095 0.866033
27820   17683   315.7000095 0.866033
```

I dissected the file and uploaded up to 60,000 rows of data and bombed out, which is 1.93MB. Anything beyond that just doesn't work. The error code is "  -- CSV file to load:  failure to upload the file >>> Error code: 1
 " error code 1.

Also how do I print a complete PHP error message instead of just the value "1" which I'm not sure what it corresponds to? ie... output print like this "UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 1"?

```
<?php
// using upload at click from http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/
// FileData is the name for the input file

$file_result = "";
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];

$allowedExtensions = array("csv", "txt");
$arrayVar = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$extension = end($arrayVar);

//commented out for “Only variables should be passed by reference” error
//$extension = end(explode(".", $file["name"]));


function isAllowedExtension($fileName) {
    global $allowedExtensions;
    return in_array(end(explode(".", $fileName)), $allowedExtensions);
}

if($file["error"] > 0){
    echo "failure to upload the file >>> ". "Error code: ".$file["error"]."<br>";
}else{
    //echo " >>> CURRENT DIR: ".getcwd() . "\n";
    $workDir = getcwd();

    $dir = substr($workDir, 0, -10);
    $path = $file["name"];
    $newFileLoc = $dir.$path;

    $file_result.=
    "<br>     Upload: " . $file["name"] . "<br>" .
    "     Type: " . $file["type"] . "<br>" .
    "     Size: " . $file["size"] . "<br>" .
    "     file uploaded to: ".$newFileLoc."<br>";

    // txt - text/plain
    // rtf - application/msword
    // dat/obj - application/octet-stream
    // csv - application/vnd.ms-excel
    // maximum 200 MB file - 200,000,000 k

    if (    ($file["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || $file["type"] == "text/plain")
            && isAllowedExtension($file["name"])
            && ($file["size"] < 200000000)
        )
        {   
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $newFileLoc);
            //echo $file_result.=" >>> File uploaded successfull!!";
            echo "|".$path;//"filePath : " . $newFileLoc;

        }else{
            echo " >>> NOT a file valid: ". isAllowedExtension($file["name"]);
        }       
}
```

?>

This is the line that was added as suggested by another user to catch the error correctly. Please let me know if that's right sorry i don't know much PHP at all. Anyways, the error printed is just "-- CSV file to load:  failure to upload the file >>> Error code: 1
 "

```
<?php
// using upload at click from http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/
// FileData is the name for the input file

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$file_result = "";
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];

$allowedExtensions = array("csv", "txt");
$arrayVar = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$extension = end($arrayVar);
```

Comment: Is your PHP timing out, by any chance?

Comment: not sure how to check, but very unlikely because I can't load 61,000 records but loads 60,000 fine. and loading 60,000 takes only a fraction of time like 2 seconds including additional processing

Comment: Does it always stop at the same record?

Comment: add this to the beginning of your script `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us the exact PHP error you get.

Comment: good point, but i don't have a way to see which record it bombs out, if it did bombed out.

Comment: @user1518600 - get it to print out the record it's processing as they're processed.

Comment: @user1518600 - See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.  It looks like your error is probably UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.  It would *not* bomb out on any specific line: only when a specific #/bytes was exceeded.  2MB is a common default.

Comment: @andrewsi It isn't processing any records, it's failing at the upload stage. I suspect that the issues is the maximum upload filesize, which is 2mb by default in most cases.

Comment: @sudowned - jings, I misread the question.

Comment: Jocelyn, and all, here's the error msg "-- CSV file to load:  <br>
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: ini_set in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\search\php\loader\csvFileUploader1.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br>
<br>
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Function name must be a string in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\search\php\loader\csvFileUploader1.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br>"

Comment: like so?  "$ini_set = "";
 $ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);"?

Comment: the code must be exactly that: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Jocelyn, sorry i dont' know much PHP, I printed it on end of the post on top, is that right? if so, it still produces the same error code so i guess i'm not doing it right.

Comment: @user1518600: http://pastebin.com/uj3sPqae

Comment: @Jocelyn, same as pasted at the bottom of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the upload size in your php.ini file:

- http://drupal.org/node/97193

Comment: nice link with detailed steps, I changed the attributes in php.ini and restarted the server, works like a charm. Thanks for the comments and the link.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set your [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) something higher than 2M
2. Your [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) should be higher than 2M
3. ensure [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) is high enough
4. [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) should also be high enough, but it should be at 16M which should be fine.
5. ensure [`set_time_limit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) is high enough

Comment: thanks for the note and the detailed steps. But since I'm a beginner in PHP I didn't know where the file was and which file. I changed the attributes in php.ini and restarted the server, works like a charm – thanks again